# How to map Postgres JSON data type in DTO and Aggentity class using Springboot and Hibernate

Tags: java, json, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I have a ResponseDto class which looks like as below:

```
public static class HealthGoalsHighlight {

    @ApiModelProperty(value = "Total number of eligible users")
    private Long totalEligibleUsers;
    @ApiModelProperty(value = "Total number of registered users")
    private Long totalRegisteredUsers;
    @ApiModelProperty(value = "Total number of users with atleast one goal count")
    private Long totalUsersWithGoal;
    @ApiModelProperty(value = "Top goal name selected by user")
    private String topGoal;
    @ApiModelProperty(value = "Bottom goal name selected by user")
    private String bottomGoal;
  }
```

This DTO was made based upon below table structure:

```
health_goals
(
  uid BIGSERIAL NOT NULL CONSTRAINT health_goals_pkey primary key,
  employer_key bigint not null,
  total_eligible_users bigint not null,
  total_registered_users bigint not null,
  total_users_with_goal bigint not null,
  top_goal_name varchar(255),
  bottom_goal_name varchar(255),
  created_ts TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW(),
  updated_ts TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW(),
  created_by varchar(255),
  updated_by varchar(255)
);
```

Now the table structure has been changed to as below:

```
health_goals
(
  uid BIGSERIAL NOT NULL CONSTRAINT health_goals_pkey primary key,
  employer_key bigint not null,
  health_goals_metric_value json null,
  created_ts TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW(),
  updated_ts TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW(),
  created_by varchar(255),
  updated_by varchar(255)
);
```

Basically now all these columns like `total_eligible_users`, `total_registered_users`, `total_users_with_goal`, `top_goal_name`, `bottom_goal_name` wil be consolidated to single column`health_goals_metric_value` as a JSON data type.

How can I write the response DTO for JSON data type column. Also what changes needs to be done in my AggMapper class.

Comment: Please share the code for your existent AggMapper class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well one way is by using converter function. You can use the converter function to get values in same format.

Change your `orm.xml` something like below on your column definition

```
<basic name="healthGoalsMetricValue">
                <column name="health_goals_metric_value" nullable="true"/>
                <convert converter="path.to.your.HealthGoalsMetricValueConverter"/>
            </basic>
```

Or if you have java file

aggentity will have following entry

```
  @Convert(converter = HealthGoalsMetricValueConverter.class)
    private HealthGoalsHighlight healthGoalsHighlight ;
```

and your class `HealthGoalsMetricValue` will look something like

//////////////////Edited converter class after comments

```
       import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

import javax.persistence.AttributeConverter;
import javax.persistence.Converter;
import java.io.IOException;

@Converter
public class HealthGoalsMetricValueConverter implements AttributeConverter<HealthGoalsMetricValue, String> {

private final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

//And then override like that
@Override
        public String convertToDatabaseColumn(HealthGoalsHighlight healthGoalsMetricValue) {

            try {                
                json = mapper.writeValueAsString(healthGoalsMetricValue);
            } catch (JsonProcessingException exception) {
                throw new JsonProcessingException("Error occurred while object serialization", exception);
            }
            return json;
    }

 //And then override again
@Override
public HealthGoalsMetricValue  convertToEntityAttribute(String healthGoalsMetricValuestr ) {
    HealthGoalsMetricValue  healthGoalsMetricValue  = null;
    try {
        if (healthGoalsMetricValue != null) {
            healthGoalsMetricValue = mapper.readValue(healthGoalsMetricValuestr, HealthGoalsMetricValue.class);
        }
    } catch (Exception exception) {
        throw new Exception("Error occurred while object Deserialization", exception);
    }
    return healthGoalsMetricValue;
}
```

This all will do the job for you.

Comment: convertToDatabaseColumn(HealthGoalsMetricValue healthGoalsMetricValue) -- In this method "HealthGoalsMetricValue" where should I define this class and what will be its content. Otherwise its giving me error, can't resolve symbol HealthGoalsMetricValue.

Comment: This will be type of your JSON cloumn in entity class.````HealthGoalsHighlight```` @sandeep

Comment: @Sandeep let me know if any doubt still.

Comment: I think I've messed up everything. Getting lot of errors. Let me try to write here step by step. this is how mu DTO looks like.
public class HealthGoalsHighlightResponseDto implements Serializable {

  private MetadataDto metadata;
  private HealthGoalsHighlight healthGoalsHighlight;

  @EqualsAndHashCode
  public static class HealthGoalsHighlight {

    @ApiModelProperty(value = "Total metrics")
    private Map<String, Object> healthGoalsMetricValue;
  }
}

Comment: This is my AggEntity class
public class HealthGoalsHighlightAggEntity extends AggBaseEntity {
  @Convert(converter = HealthGoalsMetricValueConverter.class)
  private HealthGoalsHighlight healthGoalsHighlight ;
}

Comment: Then I have created a new java file with the name HealthGoalsMetricValueConverter.java and pasted your given code. But lot of class names are not resolving.

Comment: Definitely blindly if you copy it will fail.
Give class names that are failing. you can follow this link for converter classes https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-attribute-converters    @sandeep

Comment: Converter class hold your custom logic. Example i have given is de-serializing json data to each objects and vice versa.

Comment: @sandeep if your problem still not resolve we can have conversation in chatroom.

Comment: I have edited converter class further. You should have maximum of your error resolved. Just make sure to give valid names of your custom classes where-ever applicable @sandeep

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215073/discussion-between-sandeep-and-kunal-vohra).

Answer (score 0):

If you can add additional library have a look at https://github.com/vladmihalcea/hibernate-types project, it's super easy with that.

With this library you will end up with code as simple as this

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "health_goals")
@TypeDefs({
    @TypeDef(name = "json", typeClass = JsonStringType.class),
    @TypeDef(name = "jsonb", typeClass = JsonBinaryType.class)
})
public class HealthGoal {
    // all other columns
    @Type(type = "json")
    private HealthGoalsHighlight healthGoalsHighlight;

    // getters setters

}
```

And if using the maven add dependency

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.vladmihalcea</groupId>
  <artifactId>hibernate-types-52</artifactId>
  <version>2.9.10</version> // or newer version
</dependency>
```

Comment: I am not using Maven. How can I use this library. Do I need to download and install in my project. If yes how to do that.

Comment: @sandeep Just add the <dependency> part into your pom.xml. And put the `@TypeDefs `on your entity and the `@Type` on the field, and you are ready to go. See this cool doc https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-map-json-objects-using-generic-hibernate-types/